# Subtracting chars doesn't overflow when it should

Tags: c++, gcc, integer-overflow

I was implementing the library function ***strcmp***, which should return, depending on the input, less than 0 when the first char array is smaller, greater when it is bigger and 0 when the arrays are equal. A clever trick I encountered was to find the first index where there is a difference and subtract the characters at the index. I thought that this would break since we are subtracting characters which could cause them to overflow, so I tested it with this program and it does in fact work.

```
int res(){
    char a = -128;
    char b = 15;
    return a-b;
}
output: -143
```

So my question is why does this work. Is `char` always casted to integer before arithmetic operations or is the compiler just being smart?

Comment: Yes, `char` gets promoted to `int` here. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion

Comment: That is extremely useful to know. Thanks for the answer.